# Kendo Grid sortable property case sensitive issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid i need to sort my column data using `sortable:true` this property my data in three formats . while sorting it takes Upper case first and lower case letter second (like A B C a b c ....).

Any one knows the solution(I search this through many blogs but i can't)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which replaces the comparer used by the datasource:

https://gist.github.com/JohannesHoppe/4161255

And here's the relevant thread I got that link from (that's also where Sankar's solution is from): http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/how-to-enable-case-insensitive-sorting-on-kendo-ui-grid.aspx

(note that case-insensitive sorting is apparently implemented in newer versions of Kendo UI, so you might just want to upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

you can sort on DataSource. So you can add a `hidden` field to DataSource and make it to lower case. Sort this hidden field.

Here is  an example:

```
userNamen = [];
$.each(obj.users, function(i, el){
     userNamen.push({ no: el.no,
                      name: el.ID,
                      email: el.email,
                      fax: el.faxDirect,
                      phone: el.phoneDirect,
                      toLowerCase: el.ID.toLowerCase()
     });
})
$("##callTo").data("kendoDropDownList").setDataSource(userNamen);
$("##callTo").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.sort({ field: "toLowerCase",
                                                          dir: "asc" });
```